# How to access keypad backlight

Tags: android

I want to access hardware keypad back light through my android app.But Device should not be rooted.Somebody help me for that.

I have solutions for rooted devices only.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the hardware back light is not possible for non-rooted devices.